# class html not found laravel 5.0

Tags: laravel-5

1. i have included the following 
       i have Add to composer.json:
        "illuminate/html": "5.0.*"
       i have Add to the app.php providers array:
       'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
       i have Add to the app.php aliases array:
       a) 'Html' => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
       b) 'Form' => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',

   when i try to update my composer in cmd i get the following error what can be the problem

   ```
   C:\xampp>cd\xampp\htdocs\sites\project\laravel\mysitegud

   C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\project\laravel\mysitegud>composer update


     [Seld\JsonLint\ParsingException]
     "./composer.json" does not contain valid JSON
     Parse error on line 8:
     ...amework": "5.0.*"          "illuminate/html", "
     ---------------------^
     Expected one of: 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']'
   ```

**the following code below is for composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*"
        "illuminate/html", "5.0.*" <!--this code is for illuminate-->

    },   //is there any problem in the following code.i have noticed that laravel is key sensitive .may be i went wrong some where but i dont know where.
```

Answer (score 0):

The second entry of your `require` array is formatted wrong. The delimiter/separator between key and value is a `:` when using *JSON*, not a simple `,`

**Current line**

```
"illuminate/html", "5.0.*"
```

**Correct line**

```
"illuminate/html": "5.0.*"
```

Now run `composer update` or `composer install` depending on your projects status. It should install the HTML and Form addon correctly now.

Also don't forget to add the new Form and Html facade to your `aliases`

```
  'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

and the ServiceProvider

```
 'providers' => [
    // ...
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
    // ...
  ],
```

In case you are upgrading to L5, you should remove the old declarations.

Now run `composer dumpauto` followed by `artisan optimize`.

Comment: after changing the line to

Comment: after changing the line to ' "illuminate/html": "5.0.*" ' i another error  ' Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\project\laravel\mysitegud\bootstrap\app.php on line 14 '

Comment: after changing the line to  "illuminate/html": "5.0.*" ' i another error Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\project\laravel\mysitegud\bootstrap\ap‌​p.php on line 14

Comment: @johnmwangi Issue `composer update --no-scripts` and `composer dumpauto`

Comment: i have having the same error.when i update composer through this command composer update .i cant find html flodder in vendors flodder

Comment: this the error i am getting now after i made all changes you told me to make  Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\project\laravel\mysitegud\bootstrap\app.php on line

Comment: @johnmwangi run the `composer` commands again that I wrote a few comments ago. Have you changed anything in the app.php?

Comment: yah I have change somethings

Comment: Yes, you should.
What are you changes? Have you checked that the namespaces and the folder references correct?

Comment: @johnmwangi Please update your post with the current error message and what you already tried

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\project\laravel\mysitegud\bootstrap\ap‌​‌​p.php on line 14